# Modifying a ListView's row behavior when rows are selected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I have a basic ListView, whose XAML can be found below.  Basically, after I populate things to it, I'd like to be able to remove them, hence the "X" button:

```
<ListView Name="selectedPeople" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=map, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
                Mode=OneWay}" Width="480" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,225,10,0"
                SelectionChanged="selectedPeople_SelectionChanged">
         <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Broadcast call targets">
               <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"   Header="ID"      Width="120" />
               <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Description" Width="320" />
               <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="30">
                  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content=" X " Visibility="Hidden" />
                     </DataTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>            
         </ListView.View>      
      </ListView>
```

I've left the X button invisible by default because the desired behavior is for it to only appear for rows when they are selected.  How can this be done, that is changing visibility of the button on selected change?  Also, once clicked, how can I relate which row/item the button was associated with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the button column template as like below with its IsEnabled Property.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="30" Header="">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content=" X " IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

or you can use the converter  or trigger for visiblity.

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter1" />
    </Window.Resources>
  <GridViewColumn Width="30" Header="">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>

                                    <Button Content=" X " Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter1}}" />
                                </StackPanel>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: The first way works great, but I also wanted to try the second way.  However, when I update my XAML to match yours I get a "The attachable property Resources was not found in type Window."  Am I missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: place the windows.resources item into windows not into grid. or you can pur the converter into listview.resources tag. that will work

Answer (score 3):

1. Bind button to item.IsSelected

   ```
   <Button Content=" X " Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}} Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
   ```
2. Write converter from bool to Visibility ([IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx))

   ```
   [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
   public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
   {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
       var boolValue = (bool) value;
       return boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
     }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create DeleteCommand (by implementing ICommand interface) in your ViewModel binded to item in ListView and bind button to it

   ```
   public class ItemViewModel {
     ICommand DeleteCommand {get;set;}
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <ListView Name="selectedPeople" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=map, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
                    Mode=OneWay}" Width="480" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,225,10,0"
                   >
 <ListView.Resources>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter1" />
            </ListView.Resources>
             <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Broadcast call targets">
                   <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"   Header="ID"      Width="120" />
                   <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Description" Width="320" />
                   <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="30">
                      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="X" 
                                        Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter1}}"
                                        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                        />
                         </DataTemplate>
                      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                   </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>            
             </ListView.View>      
          </ListView>
```

And not forget  create Create Deletecommand

Comment: It is similar to @syned, but i use Use an existing converter and  I binding command parameter.